# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: javascript, mern

I am getting an error while showcasing single product on screen, the error is stated as-

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
```

The code which is causing the error is

```
function ProductScreen({ match }) {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`)

      setProduct(data)
    }

    fetchProduct()
  }, [match])
```

I guess the error is of match.params.id, But I am having a hard time to resolve the error.Can anyone know the fix to this error?

Comment: Which `react-rotuer-dom` version are you using?? If you are using `v6`, then it does not pass `historyProps`.

Comment: Well the current version I am using is -"    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
"

Answer (score 0):

You passed props into `ProductScreen` but `props.match` is undefined.
Try giving `props.match` a non-empty value then it should work.

Comment: I tried mentioning a specific id instead of '${match.params.id}', it worked but as there will be different product and we can't open a specific product for all of them

Answer (score 0):

Then use other ways like `useNavigate` hook to access history and navigate. Refer to official [Doc](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview). `v6.0.2` does not pass history props and in `match.params.id`, `match` is `undefined` and that's why you are getting this error when you are trying to access `match.params` as `undefined` can't have a property.

You have to handle it differently.

---

> The above code shows the error- "'data' is not defined.eslintno-undef" and "'data' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) "

You are getting this error because, **`const` is `block scoped`**

```
if (match) {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
}
setProduct(data)
```

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables declared using the let keyword. The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment (i.e. by using the assignment operator), and it can't be redeclared (i.e. through a variable declaration).

You can handle it by,

```
let data;
if (match) {
    ({ data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`))
}
setProduct(data)
```

---

I would suggest, you can go through basics for better understanding.